# Module name not found for cv2

Tags: python, opencv

Currently, I'm using this to guide me with my project " https://github.com/hanyazou/TelloPy/blob/develop-0.7.0/tellopy/examples/video_effect.py "

but I have some issues running it, but to my knowledge, I believed I have cv2 installed in my PC. I'm using Windows 10-64bits if that helps..

The error was:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "video_effect.py" , line 5, in module

import cv2.cv2 as cv2 # for avoidance of pylint error

ImportError: No module found cv2

Comment: Did you run it with python 2 or 3? The tutorial you are following uses 2.

Comment: I'm currently running it on python 2.7.

Comment: Did you `pip install opencv-python`?

Comment: Yes I did, requirements have been met was what I got which means I have it installed.